# Using ARGV When Recursing through Directories in Perl

Tags: perl, argv

What I am trying to do is get my program to recurse through a directory and for all of those files within the directory, search each file for the word "ERROR" and then print the instance of it out in a seperate file.  I was able to do this without making it recursive, i.e. just entering which files to check manually in the cmd.  I was wondering what the proper way to use ARGV when recursing is.  Here is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "c:/programs";

find(\&searchForErrors, $dir);

sub searchForErrors()
{
my $seen = 0;

if (-f){
    my $file = $_;
    my @errors = ();

    open FILE, $file;
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    close FILE;

    for my $line (@lines){
        if (/ERROR/ ){
        push(@errors, "ERROR in line $.\n");
        print FILE "ERROR in line $.:$1\n" if (/Error\s+(.+)/);
    }
    open FILE, ">$file";
    print FILE @lines;
    close FILE;
    }
}
}
```

What I need to know is how I can incorporate ARGV so that the program will read in each file in the directory, perform the search, and then output the results of the search to a file.  I hope I have explained my question adequately, if you need any clarification, let me know what is confusing.  The more explanation you can give with the answer, the better.  Thank you!

Comment: You overwrite your input file with output. That seems like a pretty bad idea, since it will truncate every file it finds.

Comment: And also, this is a duplicate of one of your own questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10918750/725418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ARGV` is usually used to iterate over files provided from outside of Perl.

```
 $ find -type f --exec perl script.pl {} +

 # script.pl
 while (<>) {
     print "$ARGV:$.: $1\n" if /Error\s+(.+)/;
 } continue {
     close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset $.
 }
```

But it's not necessary. You could also do:

```
 use File::Find::Rule qw( );

 @ARGV = File::Find::Rule->file->in('.');
 while (<>) {
     print "$ARGV:$.: $1\n" if /Error\s+(.+)/;
 } continue {
     close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset $.
 }
```

I prefer [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule), but you could stick with [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) for reasons that should be obvious if you compare the above snippet with the following snippet:

```
use File::Find qw( find );

@ARGV = ();
find({ wanted => sub { push @ARGV, $_ if -f }, no_chdir => 1 }, '.');

 while (<>) {
     print "$ARGV:$.: $1\n" if /Error\s+(.+)/;
 } continue {
     close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset $.
 }
```

PS - You're replacing each file with an exact copy of itself, and you're populating an array you never use. I omitted that code from my version.

Comment: It's not letting me use File::Find::Rule, it says that it can't locate it in @INC.  Is there something I need to download/add to my perl for this to work?

Comment: Do you have it installed? Feel free to use File::Find if you want. It's just simpler with File::Find::Rule.

Comment: I did some checking in cmd an apparenlty I don't have Find::File::Rule and can't download it right now.  Would I just substitute Find::File for Find::File::Rule in the code, or are there other changes to be made?  I'm new at this, so please bear with me

Comment: I'm using File::Find::Rule to create a list of names. You'd have to do the same using File::Find. You can't just change the "use" line.

Comment: Okay I am lost now...could you maybe help me out with how to use File::Find instead of File::Find::Rule?  Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: Added File::Find version to answer.

Comment: Thanks so much - sorry to keep asking for more and more help but you just seem to know nearly everything!  Greatly appreciated.